# usermodehelper usage - executing shell script from the kernel

Tags: linux, shell, kernel, executable

This function is completely new for me -

Can someone clarify some questions on the usage of usermodehelper?  Specifically, I am interested in executing a shell script in some manner.

The following works with either of the two "char *argv" lines  executed-

```
static int uhm_test( void)
{
//Both of these work
    char *argv[] = {"/usr/bin/logger", "HELP!!!!!!!!", NULL };
//  char *argv[] = {"/usr/bin/touch", "/home/foo/test", NULL };
    static char *envp[] = {
            "HOME=/",
            "TERM=linux",
            "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };
    printk(KERN_INFO "In uhm_test\n");
    return  call_usermodehelper( argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC );
}
```

Neither of the following versions work (either of the two argv lines).  The printk shows that the call to uhm_test2 is being executed, and the shell script runs correctly from the command line.  The shell script "/home/foo/run_test" contains "/usr/bin/touch /home/foo/test" and runs fine when invoked from the command line.

The file '/home/foo/test' is not created in either version below.

```
static int uhm_test2( void)
{
//Neither of these work.  Neither generates an error as far as I can tell
    //char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/foo/run_test",  NULL };
    char *argv[] = {"/home/foo/run_test",  NULL };
    static char *envp[] = {
            "HOME=/",
            "TERM=linux",
            "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };
    printk(KERN_INFO "In uhm_test2 - argv[0] = %s, argv[1] = %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    return  call_usermodehelper( argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC );
}
```

I've searched quite a bit and not yet found anything that explains why a script would be handled differently than an executable binary?

Comment: Have you tried to call this command from user space using `execve`, and set exactly same arguments and environment?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have been (and am still) attempting execve, sys_execve and do_execve.  Not successful yet, but I think this is due to my own lack of knowledge.  Haven't been able to compile using execve.  sys_execve runs but hangs the process (not the system).  Will give more details (in the original post) when I have them.

Comment: Oh, no. Write **user-space** program, and use `execve` in it. Test with simple calling from terminal is not sufficient, as it use different environment from one you use in `call_usermodehelper`.

Comment: Yes, surprisingly this is exactly what I did about an hour ago.  Finally realized what you had meant, tried it,  and it works fine.

Comment: So `execve` works for you, but `call_usermodehelper` doesn't, while it is called with exactly same environment and under the same user?

Comment: @Tsyvarev No, I phrased poorly.  execvp allows me to run my own (User Space) C program (called via usermodehelper in Kernel) which can accomplish what I need.  The C program calls other executables via execvp but still fails when calling a script via execvp.  However, I can now see more information from within the C program so I can continue to investigate calling a script.  Right now the script is executed A) when the script is called from the command line, B) when the C executable is called form the command line, but not C) when the C executable is called from Kernel Space.

Comment: Experiment with `char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/strace /bin/bash -c /home/foo/run_test >&/tmp/out",  NULL };` and examine `/tmp/out` - in particular look for `execve`, `/home/foo/run_test` and associated errors.